# How to pass message from site to host and get response in google-chrome-extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

There is a plugin written for google-chrome that connects messages from the site to the user's computer. A mandatory requirement is that the plug-in through the background.js script keeps a constant connection, in fact, it keeps it through the port, but I cannot send the response received from the host to the site in any way.

That is, I send a message from the site to the plugin like this:
// script on the site

```
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extensionId, {type: "SEND_FROM_WEB_SITE"}, function(response){
            console.log(response)
    })
```

Here I establish a permanent connection to the user's computer through the port, receive a message from the website, and try to send the response back to the site.
// script background.js

```
// establishing a connection
connect()
function onNativeMessage(message){
    if(message.type == 'GET_FROM_HOST') {
        // HERE I RECEIVE AN ANSWER FROM THE USER'S COMPUTER WHICH SHOULD BE TRANSFERRED TO THE SITE? QUESTION HOW
        console.log(message);
    }
}
function connect(){
    port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostName);
    port.onMessage.addListener(onNativeMessage);
}
function sendNativeMessage(message) {
    port.postMessage(message);
}

// listening to the message from the website
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) { 
    if (request.type == "GET_FROM_WEB_SITE"){

            // WE RECEIVE A MESSAGE FROM THE WEE SITE AND SEND IT TO THE USER'S COMPUTER, HOW DO I TRANSFER THROUGH "sendResponse" THE RESPONSE TO THE SITE
            sendNativeMessage(request);
      }
    });
```

Just in case, the manifest file with permissions // manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "app plugin",
  "short_name": "app",
  "description": "app",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": ["nativeMessaging", "activeTab", "tabs", "storage"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to remember `sendResponse` until the response from the native host is received and use `return true` to keep onMessageExternal channel open:

```js
let savedSendResponse;
let port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostName);
port.onMessage.addListener(message => {
  if (savedSendResponse) {
    savedSendResponse(message);
    savedSendResponse = null;
  }
});

chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  port.postMessage(request);
  savedSendResponse = sendResponse;
  return true; // keep the channel open until savedSendResponse is called
});
```

However, a complication will arise if a) your host app processes messages asynchronously and b) several tabs with the same site may be opened and each could send a message. In this case we need to separately remember each `sendResponse`. We can do it by assigning a temporary internal id to the messages between the host and the extension. Host app should read this `id` from the messages and write the same `id` in its responses.

```js
let sendMap = new Map();
let port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostName);
port.onMessage.addListener(message => {
  const send = sendMap.get(message.id);
  if (send) {
    sendMap.delete(message.id);
    send(message);
  }
});

chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  request.id = performance.now();
  sendMap.set(request.id, sendResponse);
  port.postMessage(request);
  return true; // keep the channel open until sendResponse is called
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was close to a solution, tried to save "sendResponse" but did not return true in "addListener"